# WinSCP delete source files in specific folders older than certain date, after successful Synchronization of directory

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I have a batch file that Synchronizes a certain folder using WinSCP.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Scripts\Logs\- Server Data - Backup !M-!D-!Y.log" ^
  /command ^
    "open ""sftp://xxx/Archive/Server Data/"" " ^
    "synchronize remote ""C:\xxx\- Server Data -\"" " ^
    "exit"
```

The point behind it is to archive data to a Synology NAS SFTP server. It works well.

I also want to delete files in specific sub-directories of the source that are over a certain date, for example 30 days, but I want to be absolutely sure that they've successfully been archived to the SFTP server.

I have a batch file that deletes log files over 30 days old, but I don't think it's a safe way to delete important files. The Synchronization could hypothetically stop working for 30 days without me noticing and then I'd be screwed, for example.

```
ForFiles /p "C:\Scripts\Logs" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Also, it would be nice if the specified sub-directories could be easily editable so that I can simply add on or remove from a list. So some kind of loop I assume would be good.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [test WinSCP exit code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#result), to see if the synchronization succeeded, before you start deleting the files:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Scripts\Logs\- Server Data - Backup !M-!D-!Y.log" ^
  /command ^
    "open ""sftp://xxx/Archive/Server Data/"" " ^
    "synchronize remote ""C:\xxx\- Server Data -\"" " ^
    "exit"

if not errrolevel 1 (
    ForFiles /p "C:\Scripts\Logs" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"
)
```

See WinSCP FAQ [How do I know that script completed successfully?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_result)

---

For a more robust solution, you should use a more powerful language, like [PowerShell combined with WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

You can start with this example, which has all the key pieces you need (iterating local files, and checking if they exist remotely):
[Recursively move files in directory tree to SFTP server while preserving source directory structure](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_moves_files_keeping_directory_structure#upload_powershell).